# Laravel 5.1 pass data to socket.io and refresh page from others

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, laravel, socket.io

I trying to send data to socket.io server from controller. In this part of code:

```
          else {
                  $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
                  $user->decrement('points', $game->price);
                  $game->owner_team == 1? $team = 2 : $team = 1;
                  $game->update(['join_user_id'=> Auth::user()->id, 'join_team' => $team, 'status' =>1]);
                  // here send info about new player to socket.io server
                  return redirect('/user/game/'.$request->game_id);
                }
```

I need to notify the server, to refresh the page for others user, when this part of code was executed. I need to know how send info from controller.